# Python replace string data

Tags: python, pandas

I am a Python beginner doing simple data cleaning.

I am stuck on this problem:
I have a dataframe:

```
  datetime
1/1/2012 00:05 
1/1/2012 00:10 
1/1/2012 00:15
1/1/2012 00:20
1/1/2012 00:25
1/1/2012 00:30
```

... continuing with 5 min frequency till the end of the year.

I am trying to change 5 continuous rows to the value of every 6th row.

Essentially, it should look like this:

```
1/1/2012 00:30 
1/1/2012 00:30 
1/1/2012 00:30 
1/1/2012 00:30 
1/1/2012 00:30 
1/1/2012 00:30 
1/1/2012 01:00 
1/1/2012 01:00 
1/1/2012 01:00 
1/1/2012 01:00 
1/1/2012 01:00 
1/1/2012 01:00
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['1/1/2012 00:05', '1/1/2012 00:10', '1/1/2012 00:15', '1/1/2012 00:20', '1/1/2012 00:25', '1/1/2012 00:30', '1/1/2012 00:35']})
```

**`pd.to_datetime`** with **`dt.ceil`**

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).dt.ceil('30min')

                 date
0 2012-01-01 00:30:00
1 2012-01-01 00:30:00
2 2012-01-01 00:30:00
3 2012-01-01 00:30:00
4 2012-01-01 00:30:00
5 2012-01-01 00:30:00
6 2012-01-01 01:00:00
```

Comment: If keeps giving me funtion object is not subscriptable when I tried to put the whole list from 1/1/2012 to 12/31/12?

Comment: Oops I got it. Thank you so much !!! I just need to separate the to_datetime and dt.ceil into 2 command

Answer (score 0):

You can step with slice notation, e.g.

```
>>> spam = tuple(range(30))
>>> spam
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29)
>>> spam[::6]
(0, 6, 12, 18, 24)
>>> spam[::10]
(0, 10, 20)
>>> spam[::5]
(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25)
>>> spam[1::5]
(1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26)
>>> spam[2::5]
(2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 27)
```